# LDAP authentication on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ldap, authentication, pam

After upgrading to CentOS 7 it's no longer possible to login via LDAP. With CentOS 6 I used the package *pam_ldap* which worked fine, but now pam_ldap is no longer available for the new version of CentOS.

Connecting via *ldapsearch* still works fine, but trying to authenticate via ssh does not work.

I reinstalled the package *nss-pam-ldapd* and reconfigured authentication via *authconfig-tui*, but it still does not work.

Below I replace my username with *user.name* and the base with *dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org*.

My host OS is a CentOS 7. All currently available updates are installed.

```
$ uname -a
Linux isfet 3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 22 19:06:58 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Installed packages

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i ldap
openldap-2.4.39-3.el7.x86_64
nss-pam-ldapd-0.8.13-8.el7.x86_64
openldap-clients-2.4.39-3.el7.x86_64
```

Content of */etc/openldap/ldap.conf*

```
URI ldap://172.16.64.25
BASE dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
```

Content of */etc/nslcd.conf*

```
ldap_version 3
uri ldap://172.16.64.25
base dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
ssl no
```

Output of */var/log/secure*

```
Oct  6 12:12:16 isfet sshd[3937]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=172.16.64.1  user=user.name
Oct  6 12:12:17 isfet sshd[3937]: Failed password for user.name from 172.16.64.1 port 18877 ssh2
```

Output of */var/log/audit/audit.log*

```
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1412590243.286:364): pid=3912 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="user.name" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=172.16.64.1 addr=172.16.64.1 terminal=ssh res=failed'
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1412590243.287:365): pid=3912 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=password acct="user.name" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" hostname=? addr=172.16.64.1 terminal=ssh res=failed'
```

Output of the command *ldapserach*

```
$ ldapsearch -H ldap://172.16.64.25/ -D cn=Manager,dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org -W -x -b dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org -d1

ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://172.16.64.25/)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://172.16.64.25:389/??base)
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 172.16.64.25:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 172.16.64.25:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ber_scanf fmt ({it) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({i) ber:
ber_flush2: 61 bytes to sd 3
ldap_result ld 0x7f9b07402110 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x7f9b07402110 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7f9b07402110 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x7f9b07402110 Connections:
* host: 172.16.64.25  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Mon Oct  6 12:04:38 2014


** ld 0x7f9b07402110 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7f9b07402110 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7f9b07402110 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7f9b07402110 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f9b07402110 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f9b07402110 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7f9b07402110 msgid 1 all 1
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 50 contents:
read1msg: ld 0x7f9b07402110 msgid 1 message type bind
ber_scanf fmt ({eAA) ber:
read1msg: ld 0x7f9b07402110 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7f9b07402110 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x7f9b07402110 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <cn=Manager,dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_result
ber_scanf fmt ({iAA) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (}) ber:
ldap_msgfree
ldap_err2string
ldap_bind: Success (0)
        matched DN: cn=Manager,dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
...
```

Content of _/etc/pam.d/password-auth

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

Content of _/etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

Comment: Do you get any results from running "getent passwd user.name" or "su - user.name"?

Comment: The user exists locally, but without a password. The authentication is against the LDAP.
/etc/passwd: user.name:x:1028:1031::/home/user.name:/bin/bash
/etc/shadow: user.name:!!:16348:0:99999:7:::

Comment: Doesn't `pam_ldap` use a different file than `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`? I want to say `/etc/ldap.conf`, offhand. I'd try to debug the module by adding the `debug` option for added logging verbosiry, i.e. `auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass debug`. Beyond this I think that the question has been muddied by you following Joffrey's advice. Please revert to your original configuration if you want others to be able to help you.

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/ldap.conf`?

Comment: Thank you! Running nslcd in debug mode helped me to find the error. I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running *nslcd* in debug mode shows the problem:

```
$ $(which nslcd) -d
...
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="user.name"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org", filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=user.name))")
...
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="user.name"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [8b4567] <authc="user.name"> DEBUG: "user.name": user not found: No such object
...
```

*nslcd* sets a filter by default. It's not possible to remove this filter or set it to blank.

Because none of my LDAP users has an objectClass called *posixAccount* the users cannot be found and the login is denied.

To fix this problem I had to overwrite this filter with an own one. Because I'm looking for the *uid* it's useful to set the filter on an attribute which is searched for anyways.

New content of my */etc/nslcd.conf*:

```
filter passwd (uid=*)
uri ldap://172.16.64.25
base dc=sub,dc=example,dc=org
ssl no
```

After changing the *nslcd.conf* I had to restart the service nslcd: `systemctl restart nslcd`

**Source:** http://lists.arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd-users/2014/msg00025.html

.

This seems to be a problem for _nss-pam-ldapd-0.8.13-8.el7.x86_64_ on CentOS 7!

```
$ nslcd -V
nss-pam-ldapd 0.8.13
```

I tried to reproduce the problem on CentOS 6, but on this nss-pam-ldapd has dependencies to *pam_ldap* which has its config file in /etc/pam_ldap.conf and seems to not use /etc/nslcd.conf in the way it works on CentOS 7.

Comment: Yes, the `pam_ldap` naming collisions are very confusing. :( There are multiple implementations that all lay claim to that module name.