# retrieving user information from ldap server using a client

Tags: ldap, centos7

I have setup an ldap server on a centos 7 and added a couple of ldapusers 1 and 2 to it. ldapsearch for users does return all the info.

Both the server and the client are virtual machines on the same host Mac.

On the client side I have installed

```
yum install -y openldap-clients nss-pam-ldapd
```

and done

```
# authconfig-tui
```

But when I do

```
#  getent passwd ldapuser1
```

I get nothing back. I have done nothing with pam setup and this is all I have done with client.

on the server side:

```
vi /etc/exports
/home *(rw,sync)
```

Enable and restart rpcbind and nfs service.

```
[root@linux1 ~]# yum -y install rpcbind nfs-utils
[root@linux1 ~]# systemctl start rpcbind
[root@linux1 ~]# systemctl start nfs
[root@linux1 ~]# systemctl enable rpcbind
[root@linux1 ~]# systemctl enable nfs
```

Thanks in advance for any clarification. Is there a way to know if my client side setup has any errors?

Comment: First NFS has little to do with your LDAP auth issues. Also maybe [this Q&A](http://serverfault.com/questions/633802/ldap-authentication-on-centos-7) is of use...

Comment: I have seen that one. slapd.conf is now deprecated for new versions and I followed this setup which seems to work for them and not me on the client side, the server side seems fine. [link](http://www.learnitguide.net/2016/01/configure-openldap-server-on-rhel7.html) guideline